# Emulating Redstone Component functionality without Stone in Bedrock Superflat

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I’m currently experimenting with a No Structures Superflat world (3 dirt, 1 bedrock). As some of you Bedrock afficonados know, a Bedrock superflat has no villages, outposts, lava pools, etc.

I have started accumulating a fair bit of redstone from witches via a funnel (waterless) mob spawner I built as I’m still trying to also get enough iron to obtain water through the cauldron-bucket combo (after killing several hundred, I only have two iron ingots to show for it - drop rates for zombies suck!) I’m still at early stages here and haven’t gone in the direction of zombie village conversion as yet either.

Given that this superflat prevents me from getting cobblestone, as wandering traders don't sell lava buckets, so no cobblestone generator; and because no cobblestone I’m limited from various item builds like levers, pistons, repeaters and comparators, dispensers, droppers, etc., so I’m wondering what I can do in terms of all the redstone I have (as well as various creatable items that don't require standard stone/cobblestone) that would be useful.

For example, what could I do that would be useful made with only redstone, glowstone lamps, redstone torches, doors, pressure plates, buttons, trapdoors (and eventually iron objects plus water mechanics) and no stone that would prove useful in this kind of world? Could I emulate a piston or a comparator somehow? Granted, I may be able to so something like a lever with a T-Flip-Flop, but a piston, is there any way to emulate this behavior, taking advantage of any glitches or bugs in the latest Bedrock edition?

Granted, I have all I need to make basic circuits and logic gates but making a redstone computer is far from my list of objectives on this Superflat. I’d like to try and build something that would work to my advantage.

I'd welcome any ideas in this area...

EDIT: Please note, I'm intentionally doing this in Survival Mode, so I'm not going into Creative Mode at any stage of this game. Villagers (once I start converting zombie villagers) don't sell lava buckets, nor do Wandering traders. I'm doing this with pure Minecraft without commands, without mods , etc., but as I said above I'd love to take advantage of any glitches or bugs currently in the latest update that I'm running (1.19.20 Bedrock)